# Solving and plotting equation for different constant values

Tags: loops, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, iteration

I have solved this differential equation (theta''(x) + (2/x) theta'(x) + theta^n = 0) by using odeint.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#value of constants
n = 1.0

#define function
def exam(y, x):
    theta, omega = y
    dydx = [omega, - (2.0/x)*omega - theta**n]
    return dydx


#initial conditions
y0 = [1.0, 0.0] ## theta, omega

x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)

#call integrator
sol = odeint(exam, y0, x)

plt.plot(x, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='For n = 1')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
#plt.show()


###### (same procedure for n = 2) #########

#value of constants
n = 2.0
#define function
def exam(y, x):
    theta, omega = y
    dydx = [omega, - (2.0/x)*omega - theta**n]
    return dydx

#initial conditions
y0 = [1.0, 0.0] ## theta, omega

x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)

#call integrator
sol = odeint(exam, y0, x)

plt.plot(x, sol[:, 0], 'g', label='For n = 2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Though there is no problem and I got my expected result. I just want to know if there is any procedure (like a loop or something else) by which I can avoid this repetitive procedure and can solve the equation for different values of constant `n` at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is by wrapping your code in a function where you specify `n`. Then use a `for` loop to iterate through a list of specified `n` and then after your loop is over get your figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def solveit(n=1):

    def exam(y, x):
        theta, omega = y
        dydx = [omega, - (2.0/x)*omega - theta**n]
        return dydx

    #initial conditions
    y0 = [1.0, 0.0] ## theta, omega
    x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)

    #call integrator
    sol = odeint(exam, y0, x)

    plt.plot(x, sol[:, 0], label='For n = %s'%n) #plot the curve and label n



#List of n to loop through        
ns= [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.]

fig = plt.figure() #declare fig

for n_ in ns:
    solveit(n_) #the function will plot curve for specified n

plt.legend(loc='best') #after loop add the legend and plot characteristics
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenT. I was expected this result and you made it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with all the values of n you want to test, then call your function for each value

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry, as I am new in python, so can you please explain a bit more that do I need to use any for loop then to call the function for each value? @leosteffen

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail here, I replied on my phone. @BenT got it, so I am glad you got what you were looking for.

Comment: No worries and thanks a lot for your efforts. @leosteffen